# Discord bot message doesn't collect reactions

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to remove reactions to my bots message once the reaction comes in, but for some reason I'm getting behaviors I can not seem to track down the cause of.

I want to be able to see when a user reacts to the reply message but I only see when the bot reacts to their own message and when the user reacts to a users message. I ran my code (below) and sent 'message' to the channel and after the reply from the bot, I clicked the reactions on both my message and the bots message. Here are the logs:

```
bot is ready
reaction by:  Lyon bot  on  reply
reaction by:  Lyon bot  on  reply
reaction by:  Lyon bot  on  reply
reaction by:  Lyon bot  on  reply
reaction by:  Virt  on  message
reaction by:  Virt  on  message
```

I am expecting to be able to see `reaction by:  Virt  on reply` but I never see it.

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();

const token = '*******';

bot.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('bot is ready');
});

bot.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content === 'message') {
        message.channel.send('reply');
    }

    message.react('').then(() => message.react(''));

    const filter = (reaction, user) => {
        return ['', ''].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === message.author.id;
    };

    const collector = message.createReactionCollector(filter, {});

    collector.on('collect', r => {
        console.log('reaction by: ', r.message.author.username, ' on ', r.message.content);
    });
});

bot.login(token);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your filter doesn't seem right, replace it with this: `const filter = (reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name === '' || reaction.emoji.name === '' && user.id === message.author.id;`

Comment: Thank you, this didn't quite solve the problem but it did show me where my issue originated at.